# Apollo client does not send headers when used in nodejs environment

Tags: node.js, apollo-client

I've got a client-side app that uses apollo/client and I'have a few server-side function where also use the client to do some light queries and mutations.
I've recently implemented jwt integration and now my server-side calls fail because of what I presume is missing headers.

here is my client setup:

```js
const wsLink = new GraphQLWsLink(
  createClient({
    url: process.env.API_URL_WS,
    webSocketImpl: isNode ? ws : null,
    connectionParams: async () => {
      const { id_token } = await auth.getSession();
      return {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${id_token}`,
        },
      };
    },
  })
);

const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const { id_token } = await auth.getSession();
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      Authorization: `Bearer ${id_token}`,
    },
  };
});

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: process.env.API_URL_HTTP,
});

const splitLink = split(
  ({ query, ...rest }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      definition.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
      definition.operation === "subscription"
    );
  },
  wsLink,
  authLink.concat(httpLink)
);

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: splitLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

and here is how I am using it in the server-side function to make a mutation

```js
await client
  .mutate({
    mutation: gql`
      mutation InsertSubscriptionId(
        $id: uuid!
        $stripe_subscription_id: String!
      ) {
        update_user_by_pk(
          pk_columns: { id: $id }
          _set: { stripe_subscription_id: $stripe_subscription_id }
        ) {
          id
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      id: session.metadata.hasura_user_id,
      stripe_subscription_id: session.subscription,
    },

    context: {
      headers: {
        Authorization: req.cookies.access_token,
      },
    },
  })
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .catch(console.log);
```

this call fails even if I use the users access token or apply an admin token for access to the DB.

As a workaround I've resorted to using fetch for this mutation (which works). Any idea why headers are not respected?

My workaround with admin access secret:

```js
fetch(process.env.API_URL_HTTP, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-hasura-admin-secret": process.env.GATSBY_HASURA_ADMIN_SECRET,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: `
         mutation InsertSubscriptionId(
          $id: uuid!
          $stripe_subscription_id: String!
        ) {
          update_user_by_pk(
            pk_columns: { id: $id }
            _set: { stripe_subscription_id: $stripe_subscription_id }
          ) {
            id
          }
        }
      `,
      variables: {
        id: session.metadata.hasura_user_id,
        stripe_subscription_id: session.subscription,
      },
    }),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((result) => console.log(result));
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to provide a context function to your mutation if you're setting your header in the link.

Comment: yes, so I figure out that because I am actually jumping on domains from my site /payment to /stripe to my ssr /stripe-success to /payment it seems like the session is lost so my  const { id_token } = await auth.getSession(); is throwing an error and code does not continue. I will have to check how to persist the session so it works without workarounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the session was lost after a few jumps between my app and payment provider. As user can't be authenticated when session is lost, I've resorted to authenticate the admin user for this ssr function